# CODEOWNERS: Exclude group from directory (git)

Tags: github

My team `<team-1>` is sharing a github repo with `<team-2>`. The repo looks something like this (Simplified example):

```
infrastructure/
       |
       |-- .github/CODEOWNERS 
       |
       |-- directory1/ 
               |
               |-- subdirectory1.1/
               |
               |-- subdirectory1.2/
              |
       |-- directory2/ 
               |
               |-- subdirectory2.1/
               |
               |-- subdirectory2.2/
              |
       |-- directory3/ 
               |
               |-- subdirectory3.1/
               |
               |-- subdirectory3.2/
```

`<team-2>` is the CODEOWNER of every directory in the repo, and my team `<team-1>` owns only `subdirectory1.1` and `subdirectory2.1`.

In otherwords the CODEOWNERS file looks something like this:

**github/CODEOWNERS**

```
* @mycompany/team2
/infrastructure/directory1/subdirectory1.1 @mycompany/team1
/infrastructure/directory2/subdirectory2.1 @mycompany/team1
```

---

Given the aforementioned, what I would like to do is exclude `team2` from every folder that team1 owns, ideally without removing the wildcard in the codeowners file.

```
* @mycompany/team2
/infrastructure/directory1/subdirectory1.1 @mycompany/team1 AND EXCLUDE TEAM2
/infrastructure/directory2/subdirectory2.1 @mycompany/team1 AND EXCLUDE TEAM2
```

What is the best way to do that without rewriting the whole codeowners logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### GitHub native option: GitHub Action

You can try and configure the GitHub Action [**`mszostok/codeowners-validator`**](https://github.com/mszostok/codeowners-validator) which can validate the GitHub `CODEOWNERS` file based on [specified checks](https://github.com/mszostok/codeowners-validator#checks).

For instance:

`notowned`: Reports if a given repository contain files that do not have specified owners in `CODEOWNERS` file.

---

### Non-GitHUb native options

#### Gitolite

If by "code owner" you means push/write access to a folder, this is not supported natively by Git, or GitHub: if you can push to *part* of a repository, you can push to *all* of the repository.

What you might consider is pushing to an intermediate gateway repository, on a server you control, and where you can set-up an authorization layer, like **[gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)**

With Gitolite, you can with VREF restrict pushes by the names of dirs and files changed.

In your case:

```
repo foo
        RW+                             =   @team2
        R                               =   @team1

        RW   VREF/NAME/infrastructure/directory1/subdirectory1.1 @team1
        RW   VREF/NAME/infrastructure/directory1/subdirectory2.1 @team1
```

Once the push is validated by Gitolite, that same server could in turn push to GitHub.

---

#### Split repository and git filter-repo

But a more natural way would be to split the repository in two, referencing the team1 content in the main parent teeam2 repository, as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.
Not easy though, considering it would involve history rewriting, and folder reorganization.

Comment: Yeah, I believe submodules would be the bet handling such situations, you could also have a look here in addition to the official documentation: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodules, and here https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/ to get started with submodules.

Comment: @UtmostCreator Agreed. But it involves splitting the repository in two first, using git filter-repo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58983975/6309

Comment: I have splitted up 2 project with default git tools, but having read [git filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), seems powerful enough, not to mention the fact that it is recommended by the owners! it really may come in handy in such situations!

Comment: downvoted because it mentions adding another service instead of answering the question about CODEOWNERS file and possible ways to deal with this using github actions.

Comment: @airtonix Thank you for this feedback.  I have edited the answer to include a possible GitHub Action-based option to this question.

Comment: @VonC running a github action to validate the CODEOWNER file is not what the question is about though. It's about enforcing ownership of the code described by the CODEOWNERS file... I'm so confused as to why this isn't obvious to you? none of what you described in your answer satisfies this.

Comment: @airtonix Hopefully someone will have a better answer then.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#codeowners-syntax), your example should work just fine.

Quote from the example:

```
# Order is important; the last matching pattern takes the most
# precedence. When someone opens a pull request that only
# modifies JS files, only @js-owner and not the global
# owner(s) will be requested for a review.
*.js    @js-owner
```

So, in this case, it seems that one of the following is the case:

- Github has fixed the issue, their docs are up to date, and your example now works just as you'd like it to.
- OR: Their docs are incorrect and Github needs to fix either the feature or their docs to accurately describe behavior.

Answer (score -1):

In theory, prefixing a line with `!` should work, since

- the syntax for CODEOWNERS should be the same as for .gitignore (see https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#codeowners-syntax)
- .gitignore allows excluding (i.e. re-including) patterns by prefixing `!` (see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)

In practice, though, I tried this and the CODEOWNERS lines starting with `!` are invalid according to mszostok/codeowners-validator checks, so, no luck.

Comment: This is documented right now. It's not valid to use `!` https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#codeowners-syntax